# Absorption spectrum of open quantum systems

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, molecules, open-quantum-systems, quantum-statistics

I'm trying to understand the properties of continuous absoption spectrum of molecules in a solution using an oversimplified quantum mechanical argument.

First, let us model our isolated molecule in vacumm (zero temperature) by a quantum system with discrete energy levels. For simplicity, assume a three-state system with energies $E_1$, $E_2$, and $E_3$. Starting from the ground state, this system can absorb photons with energies that are equal to the difference between the energies of the other two states and the energy of the ground state, $E_2-E_1$ and $E_3-E_1$. The absorption spectrum of this system is given by two delta peaks $\delta(E_2-E_1)+ \delta(E_3-E_1)$.

Now, we want to put the molecule in a solution. I try to model this by opening this quantum system by putting it in contact with a thermal bath with temperature $T$ and pressure $P$. (I know that putting a molecule in a solution automatically moves the energy levels, but for simplicity, I ignore the any deterministic shift in the energy levels.) Due to the thermal fluctuations, the interaction of the molecules in the solution with our system cause fluctuations in the energy levels of the system. I suspect that the system is then able to absorb photons with energies that are in the neighborhood of $E_2-E_1$ or $E_3-E_1$. I would expect the probability of absorption of a photon with a given energy would be given by something that looks like this:

[image]

My questions are

1. Is my guess about how the absorption peaks widen in the presence of a bath correct?
2. Is there a general way to compute (approximate) the absorption probabilities as a function of the energy of the photons?
3. Most importantly, this is what I need: **How do the widths of these peaks depend on their energy** (if they do)?

Comment: The "temperature bath" is a macroscopic concept. The microscopic theory requires an electromagnetic interaction Hamiltonian that models the fluctuating local field that the molecules are exposed to. Can it be done from first principles? I doubt it, but I am sure there is plenty of molecular dynamics research that has developed specific approximations that have been tested experimentally. Did you search the literature? What happens to the spectra depends heavily on the molecule. pH sensitive dyes, for instance, completely change their color depending on acidity. .

Comment: @FlatterMann Thank you for your comment. This is not my field, and I'm really struggling to understand anything I find in the literature (I haven't done anything quantum related since graduate school which was a while ago). As for whether this can be done from first principles, I hope that there is an answer for question 3 that doesn't depend on the details of the system, possibly through a stochastic thermodynamics argument. But to be frank, I have no idea if this depends on the details of the system or not. Maybe an argument for a particle in a box would help conjecture something.

Comment: Yeah, I am afraid that you will find molecular spectra alone VERY unwieldy. One can certainly do thermodynamics on top, but that does not simplify the situation. Natural line widths are primarily a matter of coupling to the electromagnetic field. That requires quantum electrodynamics, if you want to go to first principles, otherwise we simply measure them in experiments. Most of this research is experimental, anyway. We still can't even calculate a multi-electron atom from first principles. Eventually we will, once we have working quantum computers.